# Invalid cast from 'System.Double' to 'System.Nullable`

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I've the following function which was based on this inital [Generic function to handle DataType Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723604/generic-function-to-handle-datatype-conversion)

```
public static T ConvertFromDB<T>(object value)
{
  return value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

It works fine.  However when passing in a double like 0 I get the following exception;

> Invalid cast from 'System.Double' to
>   'System.Nullable`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

I've tried casting as a float but still the same.  Any ideas why this is happening ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply : that isn't a supported usage of `Convert.ChangeType`. You need to give it the non-nullable form, i.e. `double`. You could use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`:

```
return value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(value,
      Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T));
```

but this will have overhead; personally, I suspect it might be easier to use a `Nullable<T>` specific method:

```
public static T? GetValue<T>(object value) where T : struct
{
    if(value == null || value is DBNull) return null;
    if(value is T) return (T)value;
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Or even better yet: use a an ORM or micro-ORM, so you *don't need to do this stuff* (also: they'll do a better job of it, by thinking about the type conversions during the meta-programming code, rather than the per-value execution code).

Comment: Thanks.  Am I going to have to call like (double)GetValue<double>(0);, because not all return types would be nullable

Comment: @Tommo1977 again, it may be desirable to have different implementations (different method names) for "might have a null" vs "won't have a null", and probably separate again for "string". However, I would **also** repeat that tools like "dapper" will *do a better job of this than you will*; if this is for reading ADO.NET data, please consider using a library like that